# WCF Service calling Windows Authentication protected URL

Tags: wcf, authentication, iis-7.5

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS7.5 running as a specific domain account.  Call it app1.  This service must call a windows integrated authentication protected service hosted within another IIS application.  Call it app2

app2 IIS authentication settings are "windows authorisation" enabled everything else disabled.

I have granted app1's identity access to the NTFS resource where app2 is deployed.

I am using the HttpWebRequest class to make the call from app1 to app2 and I am setting the request.credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials

I keep getting a 401 unauthorised response.

Any ideas?  It must be something simple :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

var _httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
_httpWebRequest.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
_httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
_httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";

Comment: How to call a service method using this?